# Transfer latest file from SFTP to Local

Tags: server, scripts, sftp

I am using the following script to transfer the file from SFTP to local machine.

Is it possible to update this script to only transfer the latest file from the SFTP?

Some examples

```
Database.bak
Copy of Database.bak
Copy (1) of Database.bak

sshpass -p password123 sftp User@sft.domain.co.uk << EOF
get /Complete2/Database.bak /home/user/.docker/appdata/mssql/backup/Database.bak
rm /Complete2/Database.bak
EOF
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'latest file' ? The script as it is bow, only transfers one file, Database.bak - and remove it when the get finishes, successful or not.

Comment: Hi Soren, basically I receive new database every day which creates a copy into the folder. I am hoping to only transfer the latest version i.e., Copy (1) of Database.bak and next time when script runs it will transfer Copy (2) of Database.bak and so on. I hope this gives better clarification.

Comment: You could do it in two `sftp` sessions. The first one does a `ls -l` command of the target directory. This produces a listing of possible database files. Then you exit the sftp, use some script to work out which of the listed files is the latest, and use a second `sftp` session to retrieve that file.

Comment: Only if I knows how to do that :) but thanks for explanation.

Comment: Here are some additional hints. You use `sftp xxx@xxx > listing` to redirect sftp output to a file. In the first sftp session, use `ls -t` to produce a listing in order of modification time (last modified file first). Use `lastfile=$(cut -f 1 -d ' ' listing)`  to assign the name of the latest file to variable `$lastfile`. Finally, in the second sftp session, do `get $lastfile`. This assumes there are no spaces in the filenames.